# Active Directory

Tags: c#, active-directory

Is it possible for a C# application to find all users on a `windows domain` such that the application runs outside the `domain` and is not on the same network may be over `http`?

Answer (score 0):

You need some component of the application to run within the "zone" where it can interrogate Active Directory.

This could be a small server-side component exposed as a WCF web service, that you can query for what you need from anywhere via HTTP (won't be secure, by default).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the security set up of the domain.  It is certainly possible, not directly over http though, to bind to a domain controller from outside a domain.  Assuming that they haven't blocked the ports at a firewall, you can use a regular LDAP connection or rely on the Active Directory classes in .NET. Most likely you'll have to use a secure connection and it will be on a non-standard port. You'll need to supply domain credentials for the connection in order to be able to connect.  Because you're outside the domain, you will probably also have to specify the domain controller to which to bind -- see the PrincipalContext in System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement, particuarly the [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345952.aspx) that allows you to supply credentials and the controller name/port.

Answer (score 0):

public DataTable getActiveDirectoryUsers()
        {

```
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name"));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("POCode"));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Active"));
            DataRow dtrow;

            DirectoryEntry myLdapConnection = createDirectoryEntry();
            List<Users> listAlluers = new List<Users>();

            DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(myLdapConnection);
            SearchResult result;
            SearchResultCollection resultCol = search.FindAll();

            //search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");//user name
            //search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("title"); //design


            if (resultCol != null)
            {
                for (int counter = 0; counter < resultCol.Count; counter++)
                {
                    string UserNameEmailString = string.Empty;
                    result = resultCol[counter];
                    if (result.Properties.Contains("cn") && result.Properties.Contains("title"))
                    {
                        dtrow = dt.NewRow();
                        dtrow[0] = (String)result.Properties["cn"][0];
                        dtrow[1] = (String)result.Properties[BusinessLayer.UserConfig.UniqueField][0];
                        dtrow[2] = (String)result.Properties["useraccountcontrol"][0];
                        dt.Rows.Add(dtrow);
                    }
                }
            }  

        return dt;
    }
    static DirectoryEntry createDirectoryEntry()
    {

        String Path = "LDAP://your.server.Ip";
        DirectoryEntry ldapConnection = new DirectoryEntry(Path, "username", "password");

        return ldapConnection;
    }
```